# If filtered range is empty then reset filter and skip to

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that after a few irrelevant processes filters column A and returns all cells that contain "N" letter (then copies the result to another sheet to be processed and then copies again from that sheet to another).

The code does the same thing for 3 criterias. (this segment is only for the "N" criteria).

**PROBLEM:** **when there are no cells containing "N" it gives an error that no cells have been found and stops the whole process.**

I need it to de-filter all filters that have been applied and continue with the next segment that will filter for cells that contain "CM" and so on.

Tried to count the visible cells and also with "on error" but I couldn't even get close to making it work. Just returns the same error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Se proceseaza informatiile introduse. Va rog asteptati! Durata estimata: 1 minut."

' it clears the sheet were it will paste the processed information
Sheets("EXTRAGERE NR").Range("A2:A2000").ClearContents

Dim Src As Worksheet
Dim tgt As Worksheet
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set Src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LISTA CTR")
Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EXTRAGERE NR")
Set NP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NEVOI PERSONALE")
Set RR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RATE")
Set CM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CARDURI")
Set rez = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REZULTAT")

' SEGMENTUL NEVOI PERSONALE
Sheets("EXTRAGERE NR").Range("A2:A2000").ClearContents

' turn off any autofilters that are already set
Src.AutoFilterMode = False

' find the last row with data in column A
lastRow = Src.Range("A" & Src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'remove duplicates
Sheets("LISTA CTR").Range("A3:A" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes

' reformat specified ranges by pasting format only from a chosen cell
Sheets("LISTA CTR").Range("E1048575").Copy
Sheets("LISTA CTR").Range("A3:A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats             

' the range that we are auto-filtering (all columns)
Set filterRange = Src.Range("A2:D" & lastRow)

' the range we want to copy (only columns we want to copy)
' in this case we are copying country from column A
' we set the range to start in row 2 to prevent copying the header
Set copyRange = Src.Range("A3:A" & lastRow)

' filter range based on column B
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*N*"

' copy the visible cells to our target range
' note that you can easily find the last populated row on this sheet
' if you don't want to over-write your previous results
```

**'THE PROBLEM IS HERE WHEN THERE IS NO "N" ELEMENTS TO FILTER AND RETURNS THE ERROR THAT NO CELLS HAVE BEEN FOUND**

```
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6   'coloreaza nevoile personale in galben
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A2")

If (Sheets("LISTA CTR").AutoFilterMode And Sheets("LISTA CTR").FilterMode) Or Sheets("LISTA CTR").FilterMode Then
    Sheets("LISTA CTR").ShowAllData
End If            

' SortareAlaZ NUMERE EXTRASE - NEVOI PERSONALE            
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EXTRAGERE NR").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear              
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EXTRAGERE NR").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
                Add Key:=Range("C2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EXTRAGERE NR").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'copiere numere extrase in sheetul pentru generarea cailor - NEVOI PERSONALE
tgt.Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Copy
With NP.Range("F2")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                         SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

Set copyRange = tgt.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
copyRange.Copy NP.Range("H2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Application.CountIf` function to find how many matches you have in your `filterRange`.

Try the code below:

```
If Application.CountIf(filterRange, "*N*") < 1 Then '<-- no matches
    MsgBox "No values with *N* in Range", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
Else
    ' filter range based on column B
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*N*"

    ' the rest of your code goes here
End If
```

To find if there is `"*N"` in entire Column B, use:

```
If Application.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "*N*") < 1 Then '<-- no matches
```